# merge all columns in data frame to a list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file with no headers and want to take all the columns in the data frame and want to "append" all the columns into a list.

for example I have df:

```
1 2 7
3 4 8
5 6 9
```

I have a pseudocode on what I want to perform

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv',header=None)
data = []

for i in range(number of columns) #in this case we have 3
    data.append(df[i])

#data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UUIC, you can try [`flatten`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html#numpy-ndarray-flatten) then [`sort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html#numpy-sort)

```
import numpy as np

np.sort(df.values.flatten())
```

---

```
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```